# Explicacion ciclo for en java

Tags: java, arraylist, bucle-for

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class E11 extends Thread {
public void run() {
    ArrayList<Integer> primos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean primo = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (Integer numero: primos) {
            if (numero != 1 && i % numero == 0) {
                primo = false;
                break;
            }else {
                primo = true;
            }               
        }
        if (primo) {
            primos.add(i);
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread primo = new E11();
    primo.start();
}

}
```

Buenas con el siguiente código que os pongo arriba se, que dice de los primeros 100 numeros enteros, los que son primos pero el **for** no lo acabo de entender del todo. Alguien me puede explicar ese **for**?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a este : `for (Integer numero: primos) {` ¿qué es lo que no entiendes de él, su sintaxis o lo que ocurre dentro?

Comment: @A.Cedano la sintaxis del for y lo que hace. El if lo entiendo

Comment: for (Integer numero: primos) es un for each. buscalo asi en google. si tenes alguna duda mas puntual, comenta que no entendes del bucle for y tratamos de solucionarla.

Comment: Está [explicado en la doc de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html): *La declaración `for` también tiene otra forma  de iteración a través de colecciones y matrices. A este forma a veces se le conoce como la declaración mejorada y se puede usar para hacer que sus bucles sean más compactos y fáciles de leer.* En tu caso, la variable `numero` contiene el elemento actual del array `primos` en cada iteracción y como es un array de objetos del tipo `Integer` debes poner el tipo a la izquierda. En cuanto al código, yo lo haría de otra forma.

Comment: Lo que haces en el bucle "for" es iterar el arrayList llamado "primos", en cada iteración la variable "numero" toma el dato actual del arrayList y lo trabaja; tanto el arrayList como la variable de iteración "número" son del tipo Integer para que tenga concordancia la lógica y es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java hay varias maneras de iterar.
Ambas se les conoce como `for` y `foreach`; esta ultima se utiliza para colecciones de objetos **(Arrays, listas y demás estructuras de datos)**.

En este caso, el `for (Integer numero: primos)` se le conoce como `foreach` en otros lenguajes de programación. Este se puede escribir también como `for(int i = 0; i < primos.size(); i++)`. Ambos hacen exactamente lo mismo, la diferencia es que en el segundo, para obtener un objeto dentro del `ArrayList<Integer>` se hace con el método `get(i)`, mientras que en el primero `(foreach)` ya extrae directamente el objeto en donde esta iterando, se guarda en `numero`, y automáticamente cuando pase al siguiente ítem, números sera el siguiente ítem.

La sintaxis del foreach en java, o el for para iterar colecciones de objetos es la siguiente:

```
for (Class x : a){codigo aqui...}
```

Donde:

- `Class` es la clase a la cual pertenece la colección de objetos de la lista a iterar, en tu caso `Integer`, ya que la lista va a guardar objetos de esta clase.
- `x` es el la variable a la cual se le asignara cada ítem de la lista (Esto lo veremos después mas en detalle como funciona)
- `a` es el nombre de la lista o colección, la cual debe de estar declarada e instanciada.

Un ejemplo sencillo, digamos que queremos imprimir 5 números dentro de una lista, y tenemos 5 elementos en un `ArrayList`:

```
5 | 4 | 9 | 5 | 7
```

- Con el `for` normal: `for(int i = 0; i < primos.size(); i++)`, para imprimirlos, dijimos que para obtener un objeto con este método debemos utilizar el método `get(i)` que es miembro de `ArrayList<>`, por lo tanto queda de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < primos.size(); i++){

     System.out.println(primos.get(i));

  }
  ```

De esta forma nos aseguramos de que por cada cambio del contador del for, se imprima el siguiente elemento de la lista de primos, y así hasta que termine la misma lista.

- Con el foreach: `for (Integer numero: primos)`, no es necesario hacer esto, ya que con el `foreach`, o con este tipo de for, al terminar la iteracion, `numero` toma el siguiente objeto de la lista, si no hay mas pues el `for` termina automáticamente.
  Utilizando el ejemplo anterior de impresión y del arreglo de números, queda de la siguiente manera:

  ```
  for (Integer numero: primos){

      System.out.println(numero);

  }
  ```

Con este sencillo código se logra el mismo resultado anterior.

Ahora, el uso ya depende de tus necesidades, el foreach se utiliza cuando la búsqueda es lineal, es decir, de uno a uno, cuando se desea recorrer la lista por todos los elementos ordenadamente como estén el el ArrayList<>. Si deseas recorrer la lista de manera desordenada, o por ejemplo, desde la mitad de la lista hasta el final, se utiliza el for normal, no el foreach.

Espero te haya servido.